# What is the best practice for IE specific CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on CSS based library and came across this issue as what is the best way of handling it.

And I know we all have this issue, as IE has some unexpected behaviors when it comes to standard web. So my question is not only for **Microsoft Internet Explorer**, as there are issues that still presents in **Microsoft Edge**.

**And yes we can handle it using javascript by detecting the browser and the version. But whole idea is to bring it to single CSS file. And the possibility of it.**

So using Microsoft provided methods or other css hacks,

#### Why Not IE Conditional Comments?

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7>  <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html class="ie">     <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>                <!--<![endif]-->
```

*OR*

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This supports only up to IE9 and it has been discontinued supporting and introduced to CSS queries in the latest. And personally I think this clutter the `html` markup a bit. Because this looks ugly when we write a CSS based library.

---

#### And About IE Specific CSS Hacks for older versions & IE CSS Queries for latest versions ?

```
/* For IE 8 & Lower css hacks */
.some-class {
   margin-top: 10px\9 /* apply to all ie from 8 and below */
   *margin-top:10px;  /* apply to ie 7 and below */
   _margin-top:10px; /* apply to ie 6 and below */
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ CSS styles */
     .some-class {
        margin-top: 10px;
     }
}

@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
     /* Microsoft Edge 12+ styles */
     .some-class {
        margin-top: 10px;
     } 
}
```

Well this is much better. And personally I believe this is more suitable when we write a CSS based library. As we will not ask user to import multiple files and confuse the users.

## Actual problem

If you notice above CSS hacks & queries, IE9 is missing. So is there a similar way to achieve it? And any other recommended way of doing it? Or any way for handling all IE & Edge version using a single css hack?

Comment: Again, you are asking for "what is recommended and why"...that is opinion based AND broad. If you can [edit] the question to remove all the subjectiveness you might get better traction.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Thanks for the tip. I removed that part. Is it ok now? And please be kind enough to suggest edit if you think question can be improve. And that will help to learn as well. And yes, if you get time only. And again Thanks! :)

Comment: In practice you will want to avoid browser-specific hacks as much as possible. Edge should be pretty good about cross-browser compatibility; the whole idea why MS removed conditional comments ("you don't need that anymore, right guys?!"). If you have something which breaks in IE, perhaps try a slightly different approach to implement the same thing, which works better across all browsers… That as my general two cents. Yes, I know that sometimes reality intervenes in this lofty goal…

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for the tip. Yes I fixed many things but there are some svg + css issues that Im facing. And did some research and noted that those are common issues. Voting up your tip! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is stop trying to support old IE versions unless you absolutely have to -- unless you have a defined requirement for it, there's not way you need to support anything under IE9 today. And even IE9 is questionable.

Once you've relieved yourself of that burden, you'll find that you probably don't actually need very much (if any) IE-specific CSS at all. And if you do, it can be handled with graceful feature detection rather than hacks.

Use of popular tools such as bootstrap will also help you avoid needing to write any browser-specific styles, as they do the bits that really are necessary for you, and you never need to really worry about them.

I personally haven't had to do any IE-specific styling in some time. If I did find myself needing to, my first port of call would probably be to use the [Modernizr library](https://modernizr.com/) to help me with feature detecting the things I needed to support, rather than trying to do anything specific to an individual browser. Other tools that can help include the various polyfill libraries out there, that try to add support for specific features into older browsers. When I did still need to support IE8, I used to swear by [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/), which helps you with support for some of the CSS selectors that IE6-8 don't support.

Comment: In some point im agree for your comment. But sometime we should have backward compatibility when we work with enterprise solutions. As they runs with policies. And yes I should consider the Modenizer aproach. Let see. Anyway thanks a lot for the answer. Voting up. :)

Comment: To be honest, even the enterprises that were holding on to their old IE versions are now giving up. A lot of my projects are for government departments, who were among the worst, but even they are no longer asking for old IE support. For the few that are still holding on, I guess you do have a defined requirement, so you'll need to write code to suit. But in that case your best option is probably just to force IE7 compatibility mode (use `X-UA-Compatible`), and write your site as if all your users are on IE7.

Comment: Yes I agree. Thats true. :)